# "Almost orthogonalizing" matrices using a signature matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory, norms

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two real symmetric $n \times n$ matrices (If simpler, consider $A$ and $B$ to be 0/1 matrices, say, adjacency matrices of d-regular graphs).

Then $||AB||_{op} \leq ||A||_{op}||B||_{op}$ since the operator norm is sub-multiplicative. Let us fix the operator norm to be the 2-norm or the one induced by the Euclidean vector norm.

I would like to increase this gap using a signature matrix $\tilde{I}$. Intuitively, I am just negating certain columns of $A$ (or equivalently, certain rows of $B$).

How small can we make the ratio (by a good choice of $\tilde{I}$):

\begin{equation}\frac{||A\tilde{I}B||_{op}}{||A||_{op}||B||_{op}}\end{equation}

Moreover, is there a constant $C$ such that 
\begin{equation}\frac{||A\tilde{I}B||_{op}}{||A||_{op}||B||_{op}} \leq C\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\frac{||B\tilde{I}A||_{op}}{||B||_{op}||A||_{op}} \leq C\end{equation}
and can we find such an $\tilde{I}$?

Ideally I hope for a bound around $\tan^2(\pi/8)$ :) Is this part of a general theory of trying to "almost orthogonalize" matrices and are there any good relevant references? I came across Grothendeick's Inequality while searching for relevant info, but not sure how related it is.

Edit: If $A$ and $B$ are both identity matrices, clearly nothing can be done. The context for this question is that the adjacency matrix of a d-regular graph has been split into the adjacency matrices of two d/2-regular edge-disjoint spanning subgraphs. The question might be more meaningful in this context.

Clearly, it cannot be a constant for all $A$ and $B$ but in this context, it would help if the bound depends on $||A+B||,||A||$ and $||B||$.

Comment: As you've noted, the inequality you are trying to establish is not true for general $A$ and $B$, so it is important to understand, what your case is. However I don't understand that. If $A$ and $B$ are adjacency matrix of a $d/2$-regular graphs (without loop edges?), then their product $AB$ would have every diagonal entry equal to $d/2$, and the sum of each row would be equal to $(d/2)^2$, not $d$. So it doesn't look like an adjacency matrices (did you mean to take $A+B$?).

Comment: $A^2$ would have the form you describe. Here $A$ and $B$ are different adjacency matrices. Essentially suppose $G$ is some d-regular graph. Suppose this d-regular graph can be decomposed as the edge-disjoint union of two d/2-regular spanning subgraphs. Then $G=A+B$. In this case $AB$ would have all diagonal entries $0$, and it is not clear what the sum of the rows would be. Per se, the operator norm of $AB$ could be large, almost equal to the product of the norms of $A$ and $B$. I want to sign one of these matrices so that the operator norm of the resultant product comes down.

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean and my claim in the previous comment was, indeed, wrong.

Comment: However sum of each row in $AB$ would be, indeed, $\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{jk}=\sum_{j=1}^n \left(A_{ij}(\sum_{k=1}^nB_{jk})\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n \left(A_{ij}(d/2)\right)=(d/2)^2$. But I now think I understand your question.

Comment: As I said, it is not possible to find a constant for all matrices $A$ and $B$. But we work in this restricted class, and a bound in terms of $||A+B||, ||A||$ and $||B||$ would be fine and more reasonable.